# Как сохранить данные из бекенда в useState, если получил их при загрузке страницы?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Я Получил данные из бекенда при загрузке страницы:

```
const handleLoad = (e) => {

    let data = []
    let span_items = document.querySelectorAll(".span__item")
    if (span_items){
    span_items.forEach(item => {
        let content = item?.textContent || item?.innerText;
        if (content.includes("$")){ 
            let full_price = content.split(" ")
            full_price = full_price[full_price.length-1].replace("$", "")
            full_price = parseInt(full_price)
            data.push(full_price)
        }
    });
    data = JSON.stringify(data)
    const json_data = {"year_prices": data}


    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/getprices/", json_data).then(response => {
        // returning the data here allows the caller to get it through another .then(...)
        console.log(response.data)
        const full_prices = response.data
        return full_prices  
    })
}
}




export default function Component() {
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("load", handleLoad);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("load", handleLoad);
        };
    });
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как теперь сохранить их в state? Пробовал так в компоненте:

```
    const [prices, setPrices] = useState([])
    setPrices(full_prices)
```

Но full_prices not defined. Нужно отдельно вызвать handleLoad? как-то типа:

```
useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("load", handleLoad);
        let full_prices = handleLoad()
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("load", handleLoad);
        };
    });
```

Как правильно передать значение в переменную?

Comment: @Grudy Это не дубликат и вопрос совсем не в ожидании данных от асинхронной функции

Comment: @SwaD Да, не вижу причин для закрытия.

Comment: @SwaD, это прямой дубликат. Все что нужно - получить значение из асинхронной функции handleLoad и передать его в setPrices - 100% совпадение с задачей по ссылке