# Получаю undefined из асинхронной функции. Как праильно сохранить значение в переменную?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Помогите разобраться. Задавал похожий вопрос [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1537940/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-usestate-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86). Его закрыли, как дубликат [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6). Я попробовал решение из того вопроса - объявил глобальную переменную и в функции присвоил ей значение, переданное из бекенда, но получил ошибку too many re-rerndes при попытке обновить состаяние. Поэтому решил воспользоваться решением из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1495814/js-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0) вопроса. А именно, перенес код с запросом в отдельную функцию, вызвал ее в handleLoad и попытался присвоить переменной значение из функции. Вот код:

```
let result_prices = []

async function getprices_from_server (prices) {

    let data = prices
    data = JSON.stringify(data)
    const json_data = {"year_prices": data}


    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/getprices/", json_data).then(response => {
        // returning the data here allows the caller to get it through another .then(...)
        
        const full_prices = response.data
        return full_prices 
    })
}
}

const handleLoad = async () => {
    result_prices = await getprices_from_server([10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20])
    
    console.log(result_prices)
}




export default function Buy() {
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("load", handleLoad);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("load", handleLoad);
        };
    });

    const [prices, setPrices] = useState([])
```

Но в консоль выводится undefined, а при попытке вызвать `setPrices(result_prices)` Получаю ту же ошибку `too many re-renders`. Объясните, пожалуйста, что делаю неправильно.

Comment: функция getprices_from_server  ничего не возвращает поэтому и получаешь `undefined` - посмотри исходный вопрос про получение значения из асинхронной функции. Там есть пример